# Does blockchain.info's json-rpc api return invalid json?

Tags: blockchain.info, json-rpc

example response for getting a block:

```
{"id":"0","result":{"tx":[1ddd2f103625405389705637ab69603de692a22e86f06428a2...
```

there should be a " after the `"tx":[`

Comment: Can you give an example query that produces the output you have shown? A request such as https://blockchain.info/rawblock/00000000000000008daa21d98148ef94f8710cc1809f0d74288b55c3cdc8fec6 appears to produce well-formed JSON output.

Comment: That request isn't using the json-rpc api.

I'm talking about something like curl 'http://foo:bar@rpc.blockchain.info:80' -d'{"method": "getblock", "params": ["000000000000000011d19133cf716fb977c3a89a1b5cba9598d745a50ba118e5"], "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 0}' -H"Content-Type: applicaton/json"

Comment: Ok yeah, that helps. I get the same sort of result as you describe and that certainly doesn't seem to be valid JSON.