# publicly available json-rpc node for bitcoin-cli connection

Tags: bitcoind, client, blockchain.info

There is a service provided by blockchain.info described on [json_rpc_api page](https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api).
More or less it describes the API that user can use to access their blockchain similar way as using bitcoin-cli to own daemon.
It usage is currently demonstrated as:

```
$ ./bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=rpc.blockchain.info -rpcport=443 -rpcssl -rpcuser=YourWalletIdentifier -rpcpassword=YourPassword getinfo
```

It looks nice but there is an information on the site which states:

> From the 1st December 2014, in order to use this API, access must be explicitly enabled, and all client ip addresses whitelisted by the wallet owner. Manage access in [Account Settings] -> [IP Restrictions]

And that's the problem, because I'm interested just into fetching some block or transaction details. I don't need any RPC which would require authorization. I don't even want to create an account.
So the question is:
**Are there any free services (or maybe it is still available on blockchain.info somehow?) which allows to use JSON-RPC against their bitcoin daemon?**
I don't care about the speed or waiting 10 seconds between each call etc.

Comment: Why do you need to use RPC calls to get blockchain data? Does their raw transaction and block API not have what you need? You could always run your own daemon...

Comment: @StephenM347 I'm developing daemon's JSON-RPC client and want to include few calls in the examples which allows users to see how it works without installing and running `bitcoind` - relatively heavy dependency, even in `regtest` as it requires an action outside of R console. See installation on [rbitcoind github](https://github.com/jangorecki/rbitcoind)

Comment: I would point out that blockchain.info doesn't run bitcoind - they have their own proprietary daemon, and that causes problems sometimes: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21831/does-blockchain-infos-json-rpc-api-return-invalid-json I agree that asking users to install bitcoind would be a pretty big speedbump - would running your own bitcoind instance on a VPS be an acceptable substitute?

Comment: @NickODell no bitcoind in blockchain.info doesn't change much as their interface for the user is highly compatible with official bitcoind, this matters for me. Own VPS is not acceptable solution for me. It's a pity that blockchain.info has such service but turned it off.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free bitcoin-cli sandbox at bitcoindev.network:

> Here is a simple sandbox environment for trying out the bitcoin command line interface! Select Start Scenario to bootstrap your own private instance!

You can check out the on-line sandbox here:

https://bitcoindev.network/bitcoin-cli-sandbox/

Simultaneously they provide a docker container for it, so your students can go up & running with their own daemon in a blink of an eye.