# Public Bitcoin Nodes? [No API]

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, full-node, nodes

i've been searching for hours now. Also on StackExchange here. Are there any public nodes that i can connect to using jsonrpc? I want to lookup stuff (im not into generating priv keys or anything) but I dont want to use any api. So are there any public nodes that I can connect to?

Comment: Not enough rep to comment that this has been asked before: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39358/publicly-available-json-rpc-node-for-bitcoin-cli-connection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [publicly available json-rpc node for bitcoin-cli connection](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39358/publicly-available-json-rpc-node-for-bitcoin-cli-connection)

Comment: Well this server/node he linked doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

Running public nodes for others to consume the JSONRPC API is not something that is widespread in the Bitcoin community. For a number of reasons, but the main one is probably that it's very low effort to run your own (you can get away with 10G of disk space and a few days of bootstrap time on a mid-range laptop).

That said, [this website](https://bitcoinexplorer.org/) (hosted by @janoside) exposes some RPC commands publicly.